# Compare two directories for files of the same name but different content

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have `dir1` and `dir2` which have subfolders and files of the same name. Both folders have roughly 1800 items and I need to compare to find which files are different. I need to be able to report the name of any files that are either, in one and not the other, or in both but different.

I have used tools such as WinMerge which can spot it in under a minute. However, I am trying to automate this process so being able to do it in powershell or as a batch command would be ideal.

From a powershell standpoint, my searches have suggested to pull the hash and compare them between files, which works, but takes forever due to the size of the directories.

If anyone could help steer me in the right direction or how I should approach this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I well, you would only have to hash files that had the same name ***and*** were the same size. that should cut the time down some.

Comment: Comparing file sizes and timestamps can be very fast. Those will not compare content. It is unlikely that files of identical size with different CreationTime, LastAccessTime, or LastWriteTime would be the same. Doing the hash is expensive, but is the only way to determine if the content is identical (or nah).

Comment: I tried to trim down the results by adding more properties that have to be the same, as you guys suggested, size and lastWriteTime. I cleared it with the people I'm making the script for and they said it's not worth the time to catch any edge cases like so. Thanks!

Comment: @ATKiwi size is a good indicator, timestamps are not

Answer (score 1):

WinMerge [has a CLI](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html) which should give you exactly what you need.

Comment: Is there a bash only solution to this that doesn't require external utilities?